# Refactor Code to ARC with third party libraries

Tags: ios, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

How do I refactor an iOS app that contains a large number of third party apps that already use ARC?

When I go to Edit>Refactor>Convert Objective-C code to ARC, the compiler spits out a number of errors since the third party libraries use ARC symbols such as "weak".

Do I have to remove all these third party libraries before I convert or is there another way?

Thank you!

Comment: What is the your deployment target. ARC is only available iOS 5.0 and above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set ARC ignore flag `-fno-objc-arc` on the class files not using ARC - This is the easiest way to me!

Also you can refactor selected targets, `GOTO: Edit>Refactor>Convert to Objective-C ARC`

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 4.6.3 (and probably in older versions too), you will get a dialog "Select Targets to Convert" when you click Edit>Refactor>Convert Objective-C code to ARC. Within this dialog, you can select the files that you want to convert for each target.